# Get null parameter in the server side after ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a weird problem in my ASP.Net WebApi application. I have this client side code:

```
 var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < checkarray.length; i++) {
    if (checkarray[i] == 1) arr.push(ids[i]);
}
console.log(arr);
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    async: false,
    url: "/api/Demande/ReservationAgendaByDrivers", 
    data: arr,
    success: function (data) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

In the server side:

```
[HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<ReservationModel> ReservationAgendaByDrivers(int[]  tab)
{
    List<ReservationModel> outlst = new List<ReservationModel>();
    List<ReservationModel> model = GetListReservation().ToList();
    foreach (ReservationModel item in model)
    {
        if (!item.id_chauffeur.HasValue) 
            continue;

        if (tab.Contains(item.id_chauffeur.Value)) 
            outlst.Add(item);
    }
    return outlst.OrderByDescending(x => x.id_demande);
}
```

I get for example, as output in the browser, this array :

```
[7, 5, 1]
```

but the `tab` parameter in the server side is always `null` !!

I need to know :

1. What are the reasons of this error?
2. How can I fix my code?

Comment: `async: fals`e dont do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody,

I fix my code by editing my code like this :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        async:false,
        url: "/api/Demande/ReservationAgendaByDrivers",
        data: JSON.stringify(arr), 
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
        .......
                                 }
       });
```

Answer (score 2):

For the ModelBinder to work correctly you need to provide the array in an object under the `tab` property. You should also remove the `async: false` as it is *unspeakably bad practice* to use it.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "/api/Demande/ReservationAgendaByDrivers", 
    data: {
        tab: arr
    },
    success: function (data) {
        // handle the response here...
    }
});
```

Comment: I get  in the server side : `tab = {int[0]}`

Answer (score 2):

#### *What are the reasons of this error?*

`int[]  tab` is expecting a var in the params named `tab` which is not there as you are trying to send an array `arr`.

#### *How can I fix my code?*

Send an object in the data :

```
data: { tab: arr }, // here tab is the key which belongs to int[] tab at backend
```

and `async:false` is not a good choice to set it to false. This shouldn't be used to set it to `false` as there are ways to do the things correctly with `promises`.

Comment: I get  in the server side : `tab = {int[0]}`

Comment: You need to change the data parameter in the ajax as posted. Did you tried sending it with `data: { tab: arr },` mind the word `tab` here.

Comment: I change my code as you said, the tab parameter now is not null but it is an empty array !!!

Comment: @LamloumiAfif well then i would like to see how you are making array or pushing the values in the array.

Comment: `if (checkarray[i] == 1) arr.push(ids[i]);` because of this it is pushing only one item in the array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96003/discussion-between-lamloumi-afif-and-jai).

Comment: chat is disabled at our environment. oops

Comment: but in the browser output I get [7, 5, 1]

Comment: even I set the `arr` array like this `var arr = [1, 2, 3];` and replace the previous code I get an empty array in the server side

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(arr);
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "/api/Demande/ReservationAgendaByDrivers", 
    data:{tab:arr},
    success: function (data) {
   .............
                             }});
```

Comment: I get  in the server side : `tab = {int[0]}`